# How to test whether variables are more frequently associated than expected by chance?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation

I have this presence/absence matrix (S2 is missing on purpose).

```
dat <- read.table(text="S1  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0", header=T)
```

On looking at the number of times a particular variable is found with another, it seems to me that S4, S5 and S8 are frequently found together. Is there a way of testing this statistically either for pairs of variables or for triplets?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Would a $\chi^2$-test of independence achieve what you want to do? You basically crosstabulate the variables of interest, and determine expected frequencies by assuming independence of features (if feature A occurs with frequency $f_A$ and feature B with frequency $f_B$ for $N$ observations, you expect frequency ($f_Af_B/N$) for $A \land B$. This can be done for any number of variables. Given the number of possible pairs (36) and triplets (84) in this case (9 variables), you need to be very careful to interpret the outcome of any one test, especially if you do not have any conceptual hypothesis beforehand. Using your intuition as the criterion for choosing the pair or triplet to look at does not solve the proble, as you used actual data to eliminate tests from consideration.